# Why does Peter Quill expect everyone to know who Star Lord is? And how did he earn that name?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)

> **Peter Quill**: There's one other name you might know me by... Star Lord.
>
> **Korath the Pursuer**: ...Who?
>
> **Peter Quill**: Star Lord, man. Legendary Outlaw

Why does Peter Quil expect everyone to know who this Legendary Outlaw is, and what did he do/achieve to earn this name?

Comment: Self-titled and self-advertised, apparently

Comment: That's just it - he didn't earn the name and he isn't a legendary outlaw. He has no reputation outside of the one Nova Corps officer that vaguely recognises him.

Comment: And even that one guy gets his name wrong verbally (Star-Prince), and in his written report (Space-Lord).

Comment: Doesn't his mother call him Starlord?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the end of Guardians of the Galaxy, we find out that the name Star-Lord was given to Peter by his mom.

> Peter,
>
> I know these last few months have been hard for you. But I'm going to
>   a better place and I will be okay. And I will always be with you. You
>   are the light of my life. My precious son. **My little Star-Lord.**
>
> Love,
>   Mom

As [FKN mentioned in his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/162884/79413), nearly every other superhero and super-villain has their own nickname, (Steve Rodgers - Captain America).

**It only makes sense Peter would want a hero name of his own while paying respects to his departed mother.**

Comment: It could also have been something that came to his mind on the spot, as a distraction tactic. I don't recall anyone else calliing him Starlord, not even his crew mates, or Yondu.

Answer (score 7):

Look at every other superheroes or super-villains. They all love their stardom. Peter thinks himself as someone special, someone who is one of the most famous in the system.

This part of conversation was supposed to be funny. Writers see Peter Quill as a funny and brave (Only when he is emotional) character in the process of becoming a Legend. He will remain funny till he becomes one.